# Youtube IFrame API stopped working in Wordpress 3.9.1

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, youtube-api

Few months ago both the Youtube Iframe Api and audio/video was working . However after updating my worpress to 3.9.1 which has better audio and video plugin i decided to use the plugin instead of my own html5 player code. But doing this the youtube api stop working. the only solution i can think of is to embed my html5 player through Iframe and displayed it at frontend. [my site is here](http://tubentertain.com) if you scroll down you will see the player from another page through iframe.

**== Thinking ==** 
this the code that load the api

```
<script>
     if (!window['YT']) {var YT = {loading: 0,loaded: 0};}if (!window['YTConfig']) {var YTConfig = {'host': 'http://www.youtube.com'};}if (!YT.loading) {YT.loading = 1;(function(){var l = [];YT.ready = function(f) {if (YT.loaded) {f();} else {l.push(f);}};window.onYTReady = function() {YT.loaded = 1;for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {try {l[i]();} catch (e) {}}};YT.setConfig = function(c) {for (var k in c) {if (c.hasOwnProperty(k)) {YTConfig[k] = c[k];}}};var a = document.createElement('script');a.id = 'www-widgetapi-script';a.src = 'https:' + '//s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflHmEgKs.js';a.async = true;var b = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b);})();}

</script>
```

I am wondering if this line : `a.async = true;` is the issue?

Any thought?